# How to iterate through user's group membership and return user if they are a member of a list of groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a large number of samAccountNames in a csv that I need to write a script that checks each user and sees if they are a member of any of 3 AD groups. I tried a script that searches through the groups and then finds the user, but I run into issues where the groups contain too many members which throws an error.

I tried looping through each user and pulling group membership,  but I think I don't know how to properly search for a value in an array, or at least I think that is my problem

This is what I want:

```
#Groups to look for
$groups = 'Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3'

#Import users to check from a csv file
Import-Csv "$PSScriptroot\Users.csv" | ForEach-Object {

    #define users variable
    $users = $_."samAccountName"

    foreach ($user in $users) {

        #Get all groups that the $user is a member of
        $membership = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | select name

        foreach ($group in $groups) {

            #Check if $group is in $membership
        }  
    }
}
#export a new csv of all $users who were found to be in an $groups
```

Looking for any help on how to accomplish this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering it's your intent to re-export to CSV, you need to think about adding Boolean columns (properties) that represent the user's membership in a given group.

I didn't test this, but it's an idea:

```
# Groups to look for
$groups = 'Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3'

# Import users to check from a csv file
Import-Csv "$PSScriptroot\Users.csv" | 
ForEach-Object {

    # Get all groups that the $user is a member of
    $membership = (Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_.samAccountName).Name

    $_ | 
    Select-Object *,
        @{Name = 'Group1'; Expression = { 'Group1' -in $membership }},
        @{Name = 'Group2'; Expression = { 'Group2' -in $membership }},
        @{Name = 'Group3'; Expression = { 'Group3' -in $membership }}        
    
} |
Export-Csv -Path "$PSScriptroot\Users_New.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

In this case, we're adding properties to the objects produced by `Import-Csv`.  Property's value will be True/False respective to the membership received from `Get-ADUserPrincipalGroupMembership`. Then, immediately create a new CSV file.

You could also go in the other direction by preloading the membership of the groups and checking the users against those stored lists.  Again untested bu that may look something like:

```
$Members =
@{
    Group1 = (Get-ADGroupMember 'Group1').samAccountName
    Group2 = (Get-ADGroupMember 'Group2').samAccountName
    Group3 = (Get-ADGroupMember 'Group3').samAccountName
}

Import-Csv "$PSScriptroot\Users.csv" | 
Select-Object *,
    @{Name = 'Group1'; Expression = { $_.samAccountName -in $Members['Group1'] }},
    @{Name = 'Group2'; Expression = { $_.samAccountName -in $Members['Group2'] }},
    @{Name = 'Group3'; Expression = { $_.samAccountName -in $Members['Group3'] }} |
Export-Csv -Path "$PSScriptroot\Users_New.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

This has the added advantage of being able to interrogate the group membership recusively.  Simply add the `-Recursive` switch parameter to the `Get-ADGroupMember` command.

Comment: I tried the first example and each row has the exact values for the groups. I spot checked some of the accounts and the data shown for them was not correct. The second example doesn't work due to using Get-ADGroupMember on groups over 5000 seems to break my script.

Comment: Fixed it, added     $user = $_."samAccountName" to define $user in the ForEach-Object Loop

Comment: Glad to hear it's working. I corrected the first example. As for the 5000 member limit, I'm not sure, but if I have time I'll play around see if I can figure out what's going on.